# Can I fish Romex cable through concealed part of basement ceiling in Canada?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, cables

I am running two 2-wire and one 3-wire Romex cables from the panel in the basement to another part of the basement. For most of the run I have access to the ceiling joists, but I need to cross a 2.5 meter section which is closed off and contains lots of ducts and pipes.

Here's the obstruction. I am thinking of fishing cable between the joists on the top right of the picture:

[image]

And a look inside the space:
[image]

This means that I can't support the cable every 1.5 meters, but Rule 12-520 in CEC says:

```
Where the cable is used in concealed wiring and it is impracticable to 
provide the supports required by Rule 12-510, and where metal sheeting 
or cladding, metal joists, metal top or bottom plates, or metal studs 
are not used, the cable shall be permitted to be fished.
```

So I just want to make sure that I understood this correctly. Can I fish the cable through, despite the fact that there are some metal ducts in the space?

Comment: I just marked your earlier question - *which is the same question* - a duplicate of this one. Normally it would be done the other way 'round. For reference in the future, please [edit] your original question to add detail, don't re-ask and make us all work at the problem again (we won't, because, we have memories).  **Editing a question bumps it to the top.**

Comment: @Harper Thanks, I'll keep this in mind. I wasn't sure what to do, b/c my previous question was too broad, whereas this one asks a more direct and specific question.